# Gulp: Insert string into .html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

1) I am generating critical css with Penthouse plugin:

```
var indexCriticalCss = '';

gulp.task('penthouse', function () {
  penthouse({
    url: 'app/index.html',
    css: 'app/assets/css/styles.css',
    width: 1280,
    height: 800
  }, function (err, criticalCss) {
    indexCriticalCss = criticalCss;
    console.log(indexCriticalCss);
  });
});
```

`console.log` outputs styles in the terminal window without error.

2) I minify assets and try to insert the styles into `dist/index.html`

```
gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(inject.after('<!-- Critical CSS -->', '<style>' + indexCriticalCss + '</style>'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

However, when I check the `dist/index.html` file the `<style></style>` content is empty (though created as expected). Any ideas?

PS: Build sequence is as follows:

```
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('clean:dist', 'penthouse',
    ['less', 'useref'], 
    callback);
});
```

Comment: Are you running `useref` after or before `penthouse` task?

Comment: @AakashThakur, added the code in my question.

Comment: OK, I moved the useref part inside the penthouse task callback, and it worked OK. Not sure what was actually wrong with assigning it to a variable.